# How to read game scores?

Tags: pronunciation, reading-aloud

Do people read, for example, "Bears' 20-12 loss" as "Bears' twenty **to** twelve loss" or "Bears' twenty twelve loss"？

Comment: [Yes.](http://ideasandthoughts.org/2016/09/28/when-the-answer-is-both/)

Comment: @N.Presley Your link seems to bear no relevance to my question...

Comment: Sorry - I just meant that both are used and neither is 'more correct'.  If someone wants to dig up audio clips of announcers, that's probably the only way to 'prove' my assertion.  Thinking only of tennis and soccer verbal conventions, I would say that leaving out "to" is more common, but I'm not as sure about other sports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways. Let's assume that, from your example, Bears is one team and Tigers is the other. The Bear are winning and the Tigers are losing.

- The Bears are winning twenty twelve
- twenty twelve, Bears
- twenty to twelve, Bears are winning
- twenty twelve, Bears are in the lead
- Twelve twenty, Tigers are losing
- The Tigers are losing twelve to twenty

Or something like:

- The score is twenty twelve, Bears are winning
- the score is twelve to twenty, Tigers are losing

Whenever you mention the score, it is normal to say the name of the team that is winning.

Here is reference to [**Football scores**](http://speakspeak.com/about-english/2-nil-and-3-3-how-to-speak-about-football-scores-in-english)

Comment: Actually, the sentence I gave is from a real sports news article. [Bears](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Bears) would never play [Tigers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Tigers), but would very likely be in a match with [Lions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Lions) :)